# How Xamarin Forms iOS generate/creation PDF file?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, pdf-generation

**I am looking for solution generating pdf file from string using Xamarin ( Xamarin Forms or Xamarin iOS)**.

**I have found libraries like iTextSharp, SelectPDF or Syncfusion and other but all of them must be paid. I need entirely free solution.**

PDFsharp library almost works:

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);
gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black,
new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
XStringFormats.Center);
const string filename = "HelloWorld.pdf";
document.Save(filename);
```

But at 'XFont" there is an error: "Reference to type 'FontFamily' claims it is defined in 'System.Drawing', but it could not be found".

Apple provides solution: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH10-SW3)  but this is objective-c that I am not familiar with and there are a lot of errors when I paste this code in Visual Studio.

Have you got solution written in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library: [PDFSharp.Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/akgulebubekir/PDFSharp.Xamarin.Forms).

I just tested and it works well on iOS.

You can reference the project inside `Core` and `Library` folder to your project.

He use `dependence service` to save the pdf file:

```
var pdf = PDFManager.GeneratePDFFromView(mainGrid);

DependencyService.Get<IPdfSave>().Save(pdf, "SinglePage.pdf");
```

Remember to delete the `bin` and `obj` folder and rebuild project if you can't run it after download.

Comment: Hi @Jack Hua - MSFT, I am trying your code, in which pdf is created but not able to save. I am using `pdf.Save(downloadPath)`. It is giving UnAuthorisedException to access the path even though I have granted permission for storage. Do I need to create `IPdfSave` interface ? and how can I access it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [SkiaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp?view=skiasharp-1.68.1), a great drawing library that can [generate PDF files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skdocument.createpdf?view=skiasharp-1.68.1).